# apt-get /usr/bin/datetime.so wrong ELF class

Tags: 14.04, apt, python

I'm trying to add a repo to apt-get bit it fails complaining over ELF headers

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:chris-lea/node.js
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 11, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 44, in <module>
    from xml.sax.saxutils import escape
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/xml/sax/saxutils.py", line 6, in <module>
    import os, urllib.parse, urllib.request
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 69, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email import message
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/message.py", line 15, in <module>
    from email import utils
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/utils.py", line 30, in <module>
    import datetime
ImportError: /usr/bin/datetime.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 21, in <module>
    from urllib.request import urlopen
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 69, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email import message
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/message.py", line 15, in <module>
    from email import utils
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/utils.py", line 30, in <module>
    import datetime
ImportError: /usr/bin/datetime.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

I've already tried reinstalling the datetime libary using `sudo apt-get install --reinstall --purge libpython3.4-stdlib libpython2.7-stdlib`

Any idea on how to fix this problem? I'm running: `3.13.0-48-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12 11:16:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Which Ubuntu version?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Comment: Please add the output of this command `apt-file search /usr/bin/datetime.so`

Comment: Getting no output?

Comment: `/usr/bin/datetime.so` shouldn't be in `/usr/bin` removing it solved it

Comment: and this: `ls -l /usr/bin/datetime.so`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this `apt-file search /usr/bin/datetime.so` returns no output:

Delete the file `/usr/bin/datetime.so` by making a backup:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/datetime.so /usr/bin/datetime.so.bak
```

and run this again:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:chris-lea/node.js
```